# Force Overlay if function returns False in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I need a way to invoke a non-closable, iframe overlay where the user will have to choose their membership before being able to access any of the pages.  I am doing a DB check for something, an if it returns false, then i want to invoke the overlay somehow without disrupting the session_start() function.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You haven't asked a question. What part of this process are you having trouble implementing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try this approach:

Select rows from mysql that match your criteria and then count them

```
$criteria = false;
if (count($db_result) > 0) $criteria = true;
```

The in the view you could do something like this:

```
if ($criteria === false) {
    echo '<div id="overlay">Your stuff</div>';
}
```

Just insert overlay div after  tag and use the following CSS style:

```
#overlay {
   position:fixed;
   top:0;
   right:0;
   bottom: 0;
   left: 0;
   z-index:9999;
   background-color: #FFF
```

}

Or use any transparent background image

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

This isn't really need a JavaScript issue.  You just need to have your PHP output the necessary HTML and accompany it with the proper CSS.

```
<?php

session_start();
include('header.php');

if ( !checkMembership() ) {
?>

  <div id="overlay">
    <form>
    </form>
  </div>

<?php
}

include('footer.php');

?>
```